# Rounding off values in a column - SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have the below values in one of the column in a dataframe

```
231204.66666666666
             376.0
          346593.5
             802.0
          346594.5
             801.0
          346595.5
             800.0
              null
               0.0
```

I just want the absolute value in this column. How can I do that in SparkR?

I found abs and round from SparkR which can do this job. But unfortunately it is not exported. Getting the below exception when I use Spark::abs(df$col)```

> Error: 'abs' is not an exported object from 'namespace:SparkR'

I am getting the same error for SparkR::round as well.

I tried the below, but the column value not changed.

```
df$col <- abs(df$col)
```

How can I get the absolute value in the column?

Comment: the sample you gave does not change under abs(). try `round(abs(df$col),0)`

Comment: @ZahiroMor - Thanks a lot. That does the trick. Could you please add that as answer?

Comment: fyi, `round(abs(df$col))` also works. No need for `,0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you gave does not change under abs(). 
abs has to be combined with round. Like, 
`round(abs(df$col))`